# bug: question with <> mangled

Tags: support, markdown

One of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634766/c-printf-on-strings-prints-gibberish/3634997#3634997) was mangled by the markdown engine. Several people noticed, so it wasn't just my browser.

The original text was `[sp][sp][sp][sp]include <string.h>` ([sp] = space)

This rendered as `include`

When I edited it to `#include <string.h>` it was fine. I checked, it wasn't a tabbing problem.

Here it is, but it appears normal, don't know why it was broken on that other page:

```
include <string.h>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce it, here. The only case the string is mangled is when I indent `include <string.h>` with a tab, and then 3 (or 4) spaces; in that case, the code line is not shown with a different background, and `<string.h>` doesn't appear.

Comment: I can confirm the issue on SO: I tried to write `include <string.h>` with four spaces at the beginning, and `<string.h> was not shown; the code line was not rendered with a different background either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3634997/revisions) and its [source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/0e93aca3-d4c9-4360-9db8-3a06e799d45d/view-source), it looks like a simple linebreak issue. A blank line is necessary after normal text to use a code block.

---

This line is normal text.
    This is a line immediately afterwards with 4 spaces in front. It has  to test.

This line is normal text again.

```
This is a proper line with 4 spaces in front. It has <something> to test as well.
```

---

Source of the above:

```
This line is normal text.
    This is a line immediately afterwards with 4 spaces in front. It has <something> to test.


This line is normal text again.

    This is a proper line with 4 spaces in front. It has <something> to test as well.
```

Comment: I left a blank line before and after the code line. This is the [result](http://img.skitch.com/20100903-kpbqcrsu6tpge1nhqsfe5cuweh.png).

Comment: Hmmm, I doubt that, assuming [the 2nd revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/cdb315b5-4640-4530-95a8-26b7feee78cf/view-source) was the troublesome source? (Indeed, the 1st revision that you mentioned gave trouble too, but that's not what Eric is describing?)

Comment: @kiamlaluno [My screenshot doesn't seem to have this issue](http://i.imgur.com/jm0Nj.png).

Comment: @Grace Note: I find strange that we get different results. Did you try on SO?

Comment: @kiamlaluno That's the only way to properly test. I used an answer on that same SO question to test this, and I'm not able to replicate it when it is properly formatted.

Comment: Any browser differences then?

Comment: @Arjan I'm not seeing anything wrong in that revision. The history it is visible, and in [this replication](http://i.imgur.com/foHKV.png) it is also visible.

Comment: I'm running IE8 on XP.

Comment: Never mind. There was a strange character at the beginning of the line; When the cursor was at the beginning of the line, and I pressed the cursor right key, the cursor didn't move to the right side, but it did move when I pressed it the second, and third time. I guess there was a hidden character.